# Copy file geodatabase using Python?

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, python-2.6

I am trying to copy fgdb from one path to another using Python.

```
copy(base.gdb,dest)
```

And got the message:

```
Error Info: 
[Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Pls. consider this in your python code. ( try to capture this error) While doing manual copy of fGDB to another folder, pls. ensure you have not opened the fGDB in arcmap. It will throw an error "*.lock" file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as a file system is concerned, a file gdb is a directory - trying to copy one as a single file will not work.  Try this out:

```
import shutil, errno

def copyanything(src, dst):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)
    except OSError as exc: # python >2.5
        if exc.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            shutil.copy(src, dst)
        else: raise
```

Comment: Important to note that `copytree` won't able to copy the file geodatabase contents if there are any `.lock` files there - you will get a permission denied error. The `Copy` GP tool will copy the geodatabase even if there are locks there (a user has open a feature class properties window or just navigate in the geodatabase in the Catalog window)!

Comment: @Alex Tereshenkov mention you cant copy a GDB if they have lock files. This isnt exactly true. shutils ignore_patterns can be called inside of the copytree function to prevent copying of the .lock files. I am not sure if this causes any sort of data loss, but I have not seen any from the numerous times I have done it.

Comment: @ThomasCallahan oh that's very useful - I don't think I've used it often. As you say, it's hard to tell what are the consequences of copying the file geodatabase files when it's in use, so this would not be likely a supported operation from Esri perspective. I wouldn't personally go this way ;)

Answer (score 14):

Another option:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000051000000

```
import arcgisscripting

gp = arcgisscripting.create()

gp.Copy_management(r"C:\test.gdb", r"C:\test_COPY.gdb")
```

Comment: `arcpy.Copy_management(r"inPath", r"outPath")` for the arcpy method (version 10 as opposed to 9.3)

Comment: Note: That when working over a Network this operation is very iffy. It will either, not work, work but report an 000260 Error, or if your lucky work with no errors.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the person running the python script has permission to create additional folders in the directory the script is run from.

What type of system are you running the script on?  Where in the PATH are you trying to run the script from?

Answer (score 3):

i made a simple script to copy geodatabases in-sub folders.It runs quite well. Hope this helps

```
import sys, arcpy, os

input_folder = "pro_mdb"
output_folder = "file-geodatabase"
curr_file = os.getcwd()

pro_mdb = os.path.join(curr_file,input_folder)
fgeodatabase = os.path.join(curr_file,output_folder)
folders = os.listdir(pro_mdb)

for folder in folders:
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(pro_mdb,folder)
    filegdb = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*","FileGDB")
    if len(filegdb) > 0:
        filegdb_name = os.path.basename(filegdb[0])
        ofgeodatabase = os.path.join(fgeodatabase,filegdb_name)
        if not arcpy.Exists(ofgeodatabase):
            try:
                arcpy.Copy_management(filegdb[0],ofgeodatabase)
                print "Da copy xong: %s" %(filegdb[0])
            except Exception as e:
                print e.message
        else:
            print "Da ton tai: %s" %(filegdb_name)
    else:
        print "Khong co FGB cua tinh %s" %(folder)
```