# How to copy File Geodatabase, in its entirety, while it is in use?

Tags: arcgis-server, file-geodatabase

I'm wondering if there is any way to duplicate an in use File Geodatabase?

The Geodatabase I have is being used by ArcGIS Server for a few of our web mapping applications. I understand I could stop the services and copy the Geodatabase after, and that is an option, but I'd have to do it at 2 AM when our users aren't online.

So being lazy and wanting to enjoy my sleep, I want to find a way to copy this GeoDatabase in its entirety while it is in use.

I am a pretty good programmer, so a programming or ArcGIS solution would be perfect.

Comment: If it's a file geodatabase, I don't think you are going to be able to copy it while your map services are hitting it, due to the locks that will be place. I've had to do this before (several years ago) and had to programmatically stop the services, do the database work, then restart the services.

Comment: Chad is right the service needs to be stopped programmatically at 2am  - also see this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24770/how-to-copy-a-fgdb-using-python

Comment: Yea it's a File GeoDatabase (I should have indicated that in the question). Dang, I was really hoping there was a way to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to copy the in-use geodatabase?  Is this a SDE file geodatabase where edits are being pushed to it?

Comment: @artwork21 It's an older File GeoDatabase that we loaded a great deal of information into for the purposes of our web mapping apps. We need to create an exact copy of it so that we can set it up on a new server. We have all the data contained within the GeoDatabase kicking around in non-locked GeoDatabase's, but I want an exact copy not a re-creation.

Comment: From what I understand, file geodatabse tables should only have exclusive locks when transactions are actively changing the data.  It should be possible to copy the geodatabase without shutting down the service, as long as the service isn't currently commiting a transaction.  Although, the services could request exclusive locks explicitly, then copying wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a program like Active Sync to try and copy it. It should be able to continually try and grab the files within the Geodatabase when they become free from a lock. The locks are only in place when the service is being actively drawn or queried.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [AGSSOM](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/net-web-adf/details?entryID=16BABD9A-1422-2418-8828-AC5EE09678BA) command within a python script to stop/start the services at 2am, which may be initiated by a windows scheduler calling a bat file to run your python script.

Comment: I agree that this could be done, but my main question is asking whether an in use File GeoDatabase can be duplicated.

Comment: And you tried to manually copy and paste it within ArcCatalog or Windows Explorer?

Comment: You get an error in ArcCatalog that it is in use and nothing is copied. In Windows Explorer, I think I may have found a way to do it. I tried coping the entire GeoDatabase, which failed when it tried to copy the lock files. I then deleted everything in the copied GeoDatabase, but kept the directory. I then pasted all non-lock files from the original GeoDatabase into this one. It worked fine, but I have some concerns that there may be some corrupt data withing it. Doing some tests now.