# Copy\ Paste folders and subfolders with python

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, copy

continuously to [Copy file geodatabase using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24770/how-to-copy-a-fgdb-using-python) , i work with arcview 10.3 and ptyhon 2.7.8. I try to copy a folder (dir_src) that divided into a lot of subfolders (all subfolders contain files and also gdb files) to other folder (dir_dst).
i try this code:

```
import os,shutil

dir_src = r"C:\Project\layers"
dir_dst = r"C:\Project\new" 
for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    print file 
    src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
    dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
    shutil.copytree(src_file, dst_file)
```

and get error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Project\\layers\\New File Geodatabase.gdb'
```

any help would be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answers in link you gave ([Copy file geodatabase using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24770/how-to-copy-a-fgdb-using-python)) shows 2 ways to do it right:

1. Use shutil.copytree instead of copying individual files.
2. **BUT BETTER** : use gp.Copy_management.